# Is it possible to set an different log level for a set of application classes on Glassfish?

Tags: logging, glassfish

Well, I've already tried to add an entry on Glassfish's Console Configuration > server-config > Logger Settings but it doesn't seem to work.

What I'd like to do is logging in FINEST level just a set of classes under, for instance: `br.com.mycompany`.

Have anyone tried something like that?

Comment: If `br.com.mycompany` is the name of the logger? What do you mean by setting a different log level for a set of application classes? You can set the level to a logger which you would have used while logging in the application classes.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'd like to do is logging in FINEST level just a set of classes under, for instance: br.com.mycompany

Unless that logger was [created](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-) by the code, [setting the log level will not make any difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172433/tomcat-logging-confusion/50177764#50177764).  You have to set the level on all the child loggers of `br.com.mycompany` or you have to write code to manually create that parent logger and hold a strong reference to it.