# tomcat 8.0x java.util.logging.Logger.log to file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm using

```
private static final java.util.logging.Logger LOGGER = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "log message);
```

style to log in my java web application.

I start tomcat 8.0.21 from startup.bat (project requirement) on windows 10. I can see all the logging in console window, including `java.util.logging.Logger.log` logging. But I can't see any `java.util.logging.Logger.log` logging in tomcat standard log files - `%tomcat%/logs/catalina.2018-07-31.log` and `localhost.2018-07-31.log`.

I can see all the tomcat logging, but not my web application logging. I need to track some problems with my web application on client machines in production, because I can't model such problems on my local computer.

I need to see my logging along with other tomcat logging in `%tomcat%/logs/catalina.<current_date>.log`. It would be better to to use tomcat logging configuration for all the projects. But using a per-project configuration is acceptable too. I have Googled the whole day, but all the recipes I found did not work for me.

Please don't offer to use `log4j`. Using `java.util.logging` is a project requirement. Here is my `%tomcat%/conf/logging.properties` file

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level = INFO

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = ALL
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = ALL
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = ALL
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = ALL
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

mycompany.package1.level = ALL
mycompany.package2.level = ALL
utils.jaxws.level = ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

From your logging.properties it looks like you are try to set the level for package of loggers:

```
mycompany.package1.level = ALL
mycompany.package2.level = ALL
utils.jaxws.level = ALL
```

You can only set the level of a logger if it has been [created in code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172433/tomcat-logging-confusion/50177764#50177764)  Specify all of the exact logger names or in code you have to create and hold a strong reference to the `mycompany.package1` and `mycompany.package2` loggers.

```
private static final Object loggerParent = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("mycompany.package1");
private static final java.util.logging.Logger LOGGER = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Comment: Package logging configuration is working OK, I just have double checked. Package prefixes I use in logging.properties apply to all the project packages and logging accordingly. I can see that logs in console window. My problem is I can't see same logs in log files.