# Weird behaviour of global logging level setting of java.util.logging

Tags: java, maven, logging

I have a pretty simple `logging.properties` config:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level     = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$s] %5$s %n
```

If `.level` is set to INFO I got all my INFO and higher messages as expected. But if I set the `.level` to FINE, FINER, FINEST or ALL. None of messages from my code is displayed (neither WARNING or SEVERE). All "internal" FINE, FINER etc. messages are displayed properly, but not those from my code.

I tried to add a specific level for my packages:

```
org.example.mypackage.level = INFO
```

but it has no effect to the issue. Once the global `.level` is set to FINE or lower or ALL, none of message produced by my code are displayed regardless their level.

What is wrong here? Is there any such a rule (I haven't find anything on the web).

I'm running my tests using maven:

`mvn test -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/my/logging.properties`

And my code that produces log messages looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

    public void someMethod() {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Warning message");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This must be related to maven. Once the app is compiled and run on its own (pure java SE - no app server, no containers) the issue is no more a problem. Only when run using `mvn ...` the logging behaves as described above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Maven.  More likely this has to do with `org.example.mypackage`
[logger not existing when you run your unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172433/tomcat-logging-confusion/50177764#50177764).

Add the following to the top your unit test code:

```
private static final Object PINS = new Object[]{Logger.getLogger("org.example.mypackage")};
```

As explained in the link above this will force create a logger that is now the new parent of all of the child loggers in your application.  This allows the `logging.properties` to work.  When you run your full application you probably have code that is creating this package logger which is why it all works.